# Camel : Failover EMS Tibco queues

Tags: apache-camel, failover, tibco-ems, ems

I have a primary and secondary Tibco EMS queues and need to send messages to the queues. The secondary will be in standby mode until primary goes down.

From camel code, I need to handle the failover scenario - if primary ems goes down, the application should send messages to secondary instance.

I have been searching sample for this scenario and finding something for ApacheMQ using

```
        brokerURL=failover:(endpoint1,endpoint)
```

Can someone help how to achieve this for EMS provider? 
Should it be something like this for EMS?

```
       connectionFactory.setServerUrl(endpoint1,endpoint2)
```

Answer (score 1):

The connection string for an EMS in HA is of the form:
tcp://host1:7222,tcp://host2:7222

Either one will be active at one point in time... the client will figure it out automatically (in the JMS(2).jar provided by TIBCO.)

Here is a [nice tutorial](http://tutorialspedia.com/step-by-step-how-to-setup-tibco-ems-in-fault-tolerant-mode/) (not by me).